Appendix to Finite von Neumann Algebras and Masas
In Section A.3 of Finite von Neumann Algebras and Masas the authors write "Throughout this section, let $M$ denote a finite von Neumann algebra with centre $Z$ and centre-valued trace $\mathbb{T}$". Then right before theorem A.3.5 they write
"In subsequent applications $M$ will usually be $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\overline{\otimes} N$ for a separable II$_{1}$ factor $N$.
In the next theorem we use the strong topology, so we assume that $M$ is standardly represented on the Hilbert space $L^{2}(M)$."
The only hypotheses of theorem A.3.5 are that $M$ is a finite von Neumann algebra. Yet the proof assumes that $M$ is represented on $L^{2}(M)$ and that there is a normal faithful trace $\tau$ such that $\tau\circ\mathbb{T}=\tau$. I don't understand how they could've ignored the extra hypothesis of a tracial state in the statement of their theorem. Is the idea that they are only going to prove the theorem in cases like $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\overline{\otimes} N$ where there is a faithful normal trace that isn't just directly coming from the center-valued trace, but that the theorem holds in the general form that it is stated in?
Also, I understand that $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\overline{\otimes} N$ is finite with many tracial states, but how can I show that there is a normal faithful tracial state $\tau$ such that $\tau\circ\mathbb{T}=\tau$?
A screenshot of the theorem statement is as follows:

A screenshot of the proof is as follows:





I don’t have access to the book you’re citing, and I’d assume to answer your question fully, more context is needed, such as the precise statement and proof of this Theorem A.3.5 - it’s impossible to know otherwise whether it’s generally applicable or not. With that said, assuming the center $Z$ is separable (or more generally $\sigma$-finite), there always exists a faithful normal tracial state $\tau$ satisfying the condition you’re asking for, and authors in von Neumann algebras routinely assume separability without explicitly saying that.

(Also, the standard representation $L^2(M)$ makes sense even without such a tracial state - even without assuming the vNa is finite, actually.)

@DavidGao There is no mention of separability in the statement of the theorem and the proof assumes there is a $\tau$ such that $\tau\circ\mathbb{T}=\tau$.

That’s an implicit assumption in lots of books, so not explicitly mentioning it may not necessarily preclude it. Regardless, to answer your question we need to at least know what that theorem and the proof are. As is, you’re asking us to interpret the proof of a theorem without supplying even the theorem statement. Please edit your question to include more context, probably the statement of the theorem and a screenshot of the proof. Otherwise, this question may get closed.

@DavidGao Do you know how to show that $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\overline{\otimes} N$ has a $\tau$ such that $\tau\circ\mathbb{T}=\tau$?

Assuming $N$ is a II$_1$ factor? Just take any faithful state $\varphi$ on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ and let $\tau = \varphi \circ \mathbb{T}$.

And also, by Dixmier averaging theorem, any tracial state $\tau$ (normal or not, faithful or not) would satisfy $\tau = \tau \circ \mathbb{T}$. So that part’s literally automatic.

Since the OP, for some reasons, refuses to add in screenshots of the theorem and its proof, I’ve taken the liberty to do so myself, as otherwise this question was missing all relevant context. Now that the context is here, I’ve retracted both my close vote and downvote.


In the next theorem we use the strong topology, so we assume that $M$ is standardly represented on the Hilbert space $L^{2}(M)$.

The next sentence in the text reads

The result is not dependent on the particular representation chosen.

So, all you need is one faithful normal trace. Because $N$ is a II$_1$-factor, it has a unique faithful normal trace $\tau_N$ (even if $N$ is not separable). As for $\def\NN{\mathbb N}\ell^\infty(\NN)$, there are lots and lots of normal traces. The ultraweak topology is the weak$^*$-topology, and in this case we know the predual explicitly. That is, a net $\{x_j\}\subset\ell^\infty(\NN)$ converges ultraweakly to zero if $\langle x_j,y\rangle\to0$ for all $y\in\ell^1(\NN)$. So any functional of the form $x\longmapsto\langle x,y\rangle$ will be normal. For instance we can take $$\tau_\infty(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} x(k).$$
When you choose $y$ with all positive entries, as above, the trace we get is faithful.
Then $\tau=\tau_\infty\otimes\tau_N$ is a faithful normal trace on $M$ (the existence and normality is Proposition 11.2.7 in Kadison-Ringrose, for instance; the faithfulness requires a bit more work to establish, if I'm not wrong).
Once you have $\tau$, you let $M$ act by left multiplication on $L^2(M)=\overline M^{\|\cdot\|_{2,\tau}}$.
Finally, by the Dixmier Approximation Theorem (Theorem 8.3.5 in Kadison-Ringrose, for instance) $\def\TT{\mathbb T}\TT(x)$ is the unique central element in the closed convex hull of the unitary orbit of $x$. As $\tau$ is equal to $\tau(x)$ on all such elements, it follows that $\tau(\TT(x))=\tau(x)$.

So you agree that the proof of the theorem is only valid if we assume $M$ has a faithful normal trace $\tau$?

I'll have to read it with a bit more care. In any case, you have David's answer now.

Since as far as I can tell, I’m the one who first applied this construction without assuming the center is completely atomic (the tensor product version of this construction appeared in sections II and IV of the following notes I posted on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.02086), I can point out the following:

The proof you cited, indeed, uses the existence of a faithful state on the center. However, the result is true without that assumption, and I’m pretty sure the result, without needing that assumption, was already known as a folklore result to experts in the field. You only need a small, technical tweak to the proof after all. As far as I can tell though, it was never written down explicitly. The study of von Neumann algebras usually assumes separability, and under that assumption considering ultrafilters on sets other than $\mathbb{N}$ is generally speaking, unnecessary. So there was just not much point in doing that. (In fact, I’ve had experts in the field advise me to just think of finite vNa as vNa with a faithful, normal, tracial state - despite the fact that that is technically wrong.)
People in continuous model theory have long known this to be true when the center is completely atomic, but without assuming separability, since there is a reason, model-theoretically, to use ultrafilters on sets larger than $\mathbb{N}$ even when the underlying algebra is separable. See Keisler-Shelah theorem.
For a proof of the general version of this result, without assuming the existence of a faithful state on the center, here is a screenshot of one part of a paper currently in preparation by me and a collaborator. We wrote down the general version of this result in this part (again, this is just folklore, so it’s really not anything new, which is why I can share it here):





